# How Many "Layer" Types Are There in Software Development?

Tags: logic, software-design

I have a conceptual question and believe Stack Overflow may be a great place to ask it. Often in my reading and learning I hear conversation of "layers" - and loosely defined layers, at that, it seems. Too, a lot of software jargon is used in describing these layers (so, for an *entry-level* guy or gal (like me), they each become difficult to get a grasp of).

So far, I have heard tell of three (3) layers that interact with each other and that make a program "run":

1. **Business Logic Layer** (BLL) - Wikipedia's got a great introductory [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) to this/
2. **Application Logic Layer** - that which is responsible for enabling the business logic layer to interact with boundary technologies
3. **Presentation Layer** (the layer I just learned of, today).

**Here's my question** (and it may not be possible to answer): how many of these layer "types" exist and - briefly - what are they?

I also encourage posting resources via hyperlink that people can consult, particularly as these layers do seem to be so loosely defined.

Comment: These three term might come from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the layers are essentially a generalization of the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) system architecture. Briefly, they are:

1. **BLL**: The 'guts' of the application, if you will. This is the logic that works on your own internal data types and does, as the name suggests, the 'business logic' that makes your application actually work. It should be as independent as possible from any particular implementation of how the user might interact with the business logic. For example, if you were building a Tic Tac Toe game, the BLL would be the rules engine that does the actual work of tracking people's moves, determining who wins, etc.
2. **ALL**: The 'interface' between the **BLL** and all of the stuff that feeds data into the **BLL**. This is going to be much more specific to a particular application of the **BLL**. For example, if your Tic Tac Toe engine had the ability to save out the results of games, the **ALL** might provide an interface to a database engine that stores the results. It would also be responsable for interfacing the **BLL** with whatever **PL** you chose to use (text based, a GUI, etc).
3. **PL**: This is the 'front end' of your application that the user interacts with. This could be built from a complicated framework like *Qt*, or something simple like a text interface. Either way, it's generally completely independent in terms of implementation from the application it's trying to expose. To continue the Tic Tac Toe analogy, you could build a relatively generic *3x3 grid with shapes and a message output* that just happens, via the **ALL**, to wind up displaying a Tic Tac Toe game. Now in practice they're rarely that decoupled, but the point is that you should try and keep any actual *logic* out of the **PL**, such that you can change the implementation of the **BLL** or **ALL** without having to touch your **PL** code as long as the interfaces stay the same.

These layers are loosely defined because they're just generalizations used to make visualizing the design of complex systems easier to reason about and to naturally guide development towards proper compartmentalization of functionality for maximum code reuse and component swappability, as well as allowing for more easily performing formal Verification and Validation and other QA tasks. There are many, many ways you can split up software design into 'layers', but these three are the ones that are typically formally described in Soft Eng course material. So there isn't really any specific 'number of layers' that you can talk about. How segmented a particular design is really depends on that specific domain and the 'buzzwords' in the industry at the time. You will however almost always find something akin to these three layers, sometimes broken into a few smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to me that the three concepts you list should be called "layers". They may be three components of a software system but they don't appear to lie on top of each other except in a crude PowerPoint block diagram.

The idea of layering relates to levels of abstraction in code development where lower layers provide the components used to build higher layers. The [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) is a paradigm example.

There can be any number of layers in a particular software system depending on how many levels of dependency exist. Perhaps there are only one or two layers within the immediate application being developed, though that application is likely to be dependent on a larger [stack](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/solution-stack) of assumed sub-structure.

Comment: I think the term "layer" has been throwing me, as well, particularly with regard to abstraction (and having been in networking for a few months, year). "Application Layer" really seems to be the only "logic" capable of taking on the "layer" suffix in that it is responsible for communicating with boundary technologies.